# How to unwrap StreamEx to a "Plain Old Java Stream"?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, streamex

StreamEx is a powerfull library but at some point I don't need its superpowers anymore.

How could I get rid of StreamEx internal overhead ? Could this pose a problem ?

Ex.

```
public void process(Path path){
    StreamEx.of(Files.lines(path))
        .groupRuns(...)
        //See below 
        .unwrap()
        //
        .map(...)
        .forEach(...)
}
```

Comment: The way I see it, a `StreamEx` is a `Stream` and standard operations are delegated to a `Stream` so there is practically no overhead (apart from one more object being created). I'll let its author give a proper answer :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no public API method to "unwrap" the `StreamEx` stream. This is done on purpose. In general the `StreamEx` class is compatible with original `Stream` API, so if you need to pass `StreamEx` to some code accepting simple `Stream`, you can do this without any fear.

The overhead of using `StreamEx` is usually very low: only one or several additional call per stream step (some of which could be eliminated by JIT compiler). This overhead (if not eliminated by JIT) appears only during the stream creation, not during evaluation, thus it does not depend on number of elements in the stream. When the terminal operation occurs, the processing is handed over to the original stream, thus in your example during `map` and `forEach` evaluation no StreamEx library code will be running.

The `StreamEx` overhead might be somewhat significant if you create many simple short streams. For example, if you create the `StreamEx` instance inside the `flatMap`. So in this case if performance matters and you don't need specific `StreamEx` operations for the nested `Stream`, probably it's a good idea to avoid `StreamEx` inside the `flatMap`. Though according to my tests the difference become significant (say, more than 5%) only on very artificial cases.

Note that some `StreamEx` operations are optimized compared to the Stream API equivalents. For example, `StreamEx.toList()` is usually faster than `Stream.collect(Collectors.toList())`. Simple create-map-collect operation like `StreamEx.of(persons).map(Person::getName).toList()` could work several times faster compared to the `persons.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())`.